# SortedDictionary with composite key: indexed by 1 property and sorted by another

Tags: c#, .net, sorteddictionary

I am trying to implement a SortedDictionary as:

```
public IDictionary<CustomAttributeDataKey, object> Data { get; } = new SortedDictionary<CustomAttributeDataKey, object>();
```

I have defined CustomAttributeDataKey as:

```
public class CustomAttributeDataKey : IComparable {
    public long CustomAttributeID { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    //ASSUMING this is used to check if there is a collision of keys
    protected bool Equals(CustomAttributeDataKey other) {
        return CustomAttributeID == other.CustomAttributeID;
    }

    //ASSUMING this is used to check if there is a collision of keys
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((CustomAttributeDataKey) obj);
    }

    //ASSUMING this is used to check if the key exists in the dictionary
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return CustomAttributeID.GetHashCode();
    }

    //ASSUMING this is used for sorting
    public int CompareTo(object y) {
        if (y == null)
            return 0;

        return this.Order.CompareTo(((CustomAttributeDataKey) y).Order);
    }
}
```

**Here's what I would like to happen:**

1. I would like to key the dictionary on "CustomAttributeID" property ONLY
2. I would like the dictionary to sort by "Order" property when I enumerate the keys.

Whenever I add items to the dictionary I don't see any breakpoints in the "GetHashCode" or "Equals" methods being hit but I am seeing a breakpoint being hit in "CompareTo". So not sure how SortedDictionary would actually work in this case scenario. I'd be interested to find out how to make SortedDictionary work in this scenario (I know I can do this through Linq's OrderBy() method).

Comment: You are not using Y.order.

Comment: Yes, order should not be part of the key for the dictionary. It is just for sorting.

Comment: You are not sorting on Order.

Comment: This is ambiguous. If you have two `CustomAttributeDataKey`s with the same `CustomAttributeID` but with different `Order` values, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: If you need to look-up the dictionary by CustomAttributeDataKey's, i suggest to simply use a dictionary using `CustomAttributeDataKey` as key and with an IEqualityComparer based on `CustomAttributeDataKey.CustomAttributeID` (either implemented by CustomAttributeDataKey itself, or as custom comparator class instance provided to the dictionary constructor).

Comment: If you then need the keys sorted by `Order` for some function, task, get the `KeyCollection` from the dictionary and create a sorted (by `Order`) copy of it...

Comment: @elgonzo - if I have different Order values but same CustomAttributeID then I would like to treat that as the same key. Order should not be part of the key that is used for the dictionary. The only key is CustomAttributeID

Comment: @paparazzo - why not? It is in my CompareTo() method - see code above

Comment: If that's what you want then SortedDictionary is not the right type for you, because that's not what it does.  Its job is to maintain a sorted list of keys that are each mapped to a value, and it does that job very well.  It sounds to me like what you want is two things: a hash table that is a map from ids to objects, and a sorted dictionary that is a map from orders to ids. When you want to look up by id, look in the hash table. When you want to enumerate ids, enumerate the orders and fetch the ids. You could build such a type easily enough and make it implement IDictionary.

Comment: Your last paragraph says that a *non-hashing* collection *does not hash* members of the collection, and that a *sorted* collection *determines the order* of items of the collection. That should be exactly what you'd expect, right? A sorted dictionary is not a hash table, so why would it get a hash code, ever?

Answer (score 0):

> Here's what I would like to happen:
>
> 1. I would like to key the dictionary on "CustomAttributeID" property
>      ONLY
> 2. I would like the dictionary to sort by "Order" property when I
>      enumerate the keys.
>
> Whenever I add items to the dictionary I don't see
>   any breakpoints in the "GetHashCode" or "Equals" methods being hit but
>   I am seeing a breakpoint being hit in "CompareTo". So not sure how
>   SortedDictionary would actually work in this case scenario. I'd be
>   interested to find out how to make SortedDictionary work in this
>   scenario (I know I can do this through Linq's OrderBy() method).

Per [The MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks), `SortedDictionary` is stored using a binary search tree (Per [The MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks), `SortedList` is stored using a sorted list of Key-Value pairs) .  This has a few implications which may be relevant to you:

1. `SortedDictionary` uses an `IComparer`, not `GetHashCode`/`Equals`.  `Equals` is insufficient to gain a total ordering and similultaneously using `Equals` and `CompareTo` would be a bad idea, so `Equals` is not used at all.
2. Retrieval and insertion into a `SortedDictionary` are both O(log(n)).
3. Per [The MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2.getenumerator), enumerating a `SortedDictionary` retains the order of the dictionary.  The way to control the order of the enumeration of the `SortedDictionary` is by ensuring that `CompareTo` orders the dctionary in the same way.

Personally, I would hesitate to order a `SortedDictionary` by an "Order" property, as sorting by such a property means you can only lookup members by their position.  This provides a strong link between object position and object equality which does not normally exist.  At that point, you may as well use a sorted `List<T>` instead.